# Bash output used in menu

Tags: bash

I'm trying to achieve  the following things by using bash:

1. Show fragment tables in MySQL
2. Take the output from it(table names and free MB) and put it in menu like option
3. After the user select the desired table name (from the above listed) make a disk space check .The space should be at least 2 times the size of the table
4. If there is not enough disk space in OS quit
5. If there is enough space and the table is below 10GB optimize the table
6. If there is enough space and the table is above 10GB drop the secondary keys,optimize table and import the keys again

I'm able to do all of the above manually but no idea how to do it in  bash. Any ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: How do you do all these things "manually"? You mean in a terminal?

Comment: Ι suggest you to write a php script.
@Xen2050 +1 Please display the code you write to do that manually.

Comment: Yes @Xen2050  yes I do them in terminal something  like the below:

mysql -e  "select table_schema ,table_name, round(data_length/1024/1024) as data_length_mb,  round(data_free/1024/1024) as data_free_mb   from information_schema.tables   where round(data_free/1024/1024) > 1000   order by data_free_mb;

Comment: I mean now I'm doing most of the steps each time as below:

-checking the fragment tables with size above 1GB
-checking the space in proper disk device example 

df -h /dev/sda

if i see that the size in the sda is enough I'm doing  (if the table is below 10G)

mysql>optimize table;

if it's above 10G I'm doing

ALTER TABLE table_name
 DROP INDEX one,
 DROP INDEX two,
 DROP INDEX `three;
 
 optimize table
 
 CREATE INDEX index_name     ON table_name(column_name;
 
 But I want all of these in a script.

Comment: Since you're already doing it all in bash, a bash / shell script would be logical (or another script language like PHP/perl/awk is possible too), you might just need to store some output & input to variables & use them in further commands. It can get complicated, I'd search for how basic bash scripts work & how to parse output, sed & awk are very powerful (& complicated), or cut, grep, head/tail...  Editing/pasting an example of your entire routine into the Q (MUCH better formatting than in a comment) might show an easy answer, but no guarantees on an answer, and it's best to understand anyway

Comment: Cool thanks for the answer .I will dive deeper in bash then and figure it out.